# Wrap an HTML element around the value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to involve an element that is within a navigation with a SPAN. How do I do that? I already got the element, but now I need to wrap it with SPAN.

```html
   let nodes = document.querySelector('nav.bs__pagination').childNodes; 
   const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      nodes.forEach(function(item) {
       if(item.nodeType == 3) {
         item.insertBefore(newDiv, item);
       }
   });
```

I tried insertBefore but without success, I need to add both before and after in the case:  and

Comment: you use `.before()` ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 1):

You could make a span element and then append the element inside of the span

```
const span = document.createElement("span") // Creates a span element
span.append(elementToAppend)                // Inserts an element into the span
document.querySelector("nav").append(span)  // Adds the span into a nav tag
```

Comment: That way you are creating the element and placing it in the "nav", but I wanted to take the element that I already have in the loop and create the span before and after it, you know?

Comment: Do you want two <span></span>, one before and one after?